# conexión en distintas funciones

Tags: php, mysqli

Estoy haciendo 2 funciones una para establecer los datos de conexión y otra para establecer el datos de la base datos.

El tema es que no sé, cómo poder utilizar la función de la conexión dentro de la función de la base de datos.

Este seria el código, muchas gracias

`````
<?php
$conexion;

function Conexion ($host,$usuario,$password){

     $conexion =mysqli_connect($host,$usuario,$password) or die('No se ha podido conectar a la base de datos');
}

function seleccionarBD($BD){

    Conexion();
    mysqli_select_db($conexion,$BD) or die('No se encuentra la base de datos');
}

?>
```



---

He probado ese código, y me da un error 
Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, bool given

Pero al poner las funciones en el otro archivo, no veo que haya ningún fallo, el fallo esta en la función? pero las variables estas en el orden correcto según pone la documentación

Este seria el código que puse  en el otro archivo
````
<?php

include('biblioteca.php');

Conexion("localhost","root","");

seleccionarBD("baloncesto","localhost","root","");

?>
`````

Comment: No veo por qué la necesidad de primero conectarte y luego elegir la base de datos, cuando la función mysqli_connect acepta como cuarto parámetro el nombre de la base de datos

Comment: Es que me lo piden que sea en dos funciones, por eso tengo que hacerlo asi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si `$host,$usuario,$password` son los mismos, sólo tienes que retornar la conexión desde la función `Conexion` y en la función `seleccionarBD` seleccionar la BD, algo así:

```
function Conexion ($host,$usuario,$password){
     $conexion =mysqli_connect($host,$usuario,$password) or die('No se ha podido conectar a la base de datos');
     return $conexion;
}

function seleccionarBD($BD,$conexion){
    mysqli_select_db($conexion,$BD) or die('No se encuentra la base de datos');
}
```

## Uso contextual

```
$conexion=Conexion($host,$usuario,$password);
seleccionarBD($BD,$conexion);
#Usar $conexion
```

## Nota

Esto tendría sentido únicamente en el contexto de un ejercicio o en contexto donde se necesite cambiar constantemente de base de datos, ya que `mysqli_connect` admite como cuarto parámetro el nombre de la base de datos, entonces, puedes incluir ese cuarto parámetro en `Conexion()` y evitar una función suplementaria.

Por ejemplo:

```
function Conexion ($host,$usuario,$password,$db){
     $conexion =mysqli_connect($host,$usuario,$password,$db) or die('No se ha podido conectar a la base de datos');
     return $conexion;
}
```

## Uso contextual

```
$conexion=Conexion($host,$usuario,$password,$db);
#Usar $conexion
```

Answer (score 0):

Returnando el valor de la primera función

```
<?php
$conexion;

function Conexion ($host,$usuario,$password){

     return mysqli_connect($host,$usuario,$password) or die('No se ha podido conectar a la base de datos');
}

function seleccionarBD($BD, $host,$usuario,$password){

    $conexion = Conexion($host,$usuario,$password);
    mysqli_select_db($conexion,$BD) or die('No se encuentra la base de datos');
}

?>
```

Obviamente tendrías que ingresar los valores en la función